# THREE.js adding bullets as sprites and rotating each individually

Tags: three.js

I have been working on programming a game where everything is rendered in 3d. Though the bullets are 2d sprites. this poses a problem. I have to rotate the bullet sprite by rotating the material. This turns every bullet possessing that material rather than the individual sprite I want to turn. It is also kind of inefficient to create a new sprite clone for every bullet. is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Rotate the sprite itself instead of the texture.

edit:
as OP mentioned.. the spritematerial controls the sprites rotation.y, so setting it manually does nothing...

So instead of using the Sprite type, you could use a regular planegeometry mesh with a meshbasic material or similar, and update the matrices yourself to both keep the sprite facing the camera, and rotated toward its trajectory..
Then at least you can share the material amongst all instances.

Then the performance bottleneck becomes the number of drawcalls.. (1 per sprite)..

You can improve on that by using a single BufferGeometry, and computing the 4 screen space vertices for each sprite, each frame. This moves the bottleneck away from drawCalls, and will be limited by the speed at which you can transform vertices in javascript, which is slow but not the end of the world. This is also how many THREE.js particle systems are implemented.

The next step beyond that is to use a custom vertex shader to do the heavy vertex computation.. you still update the buffergeometry each frame, but instead of transforming verts, you're just writing the position of the sprite into each of the 4 verts, and letting the vertex shader take care of figuring out which of the 4 verts it's transforming (possibly based on the UV coordinate, or stored in one of the vertex color channels..., .r for instace) and which sprite to render from your sprite atlas (a single texture/canvas with all your sprites layed out on a grid) encoded in the .g of the vertex color..

The next step beyond that, is to not update the BufferGeometry every frame, but store both position and velocity of the sprite in the vertex data.. and only pass a time offset uniform into the vertex shader.. then the vertex shader can handle integrating the sprite position over a longer time period. This only works for sprites that have deterministic behavior, or behavior that can be derived from a texture data source like a noise texture or warping texture. Things like smoke, explosions, etc.

You can extend these techniques to draw gigantic scrolling tilemaps. I've used these techniques to make multilayer scrolling/zoomable hexmaps that were 2048 hexes square, (which is a pretty huge map)(~4m triangles). with multiple layers of sprites on top of that, at 60hz.

Here the original stemkoski particle system for reference:
http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Particle-Engine.html

and:

https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/ParticleSystem-Dynamic.html